# ASP.net Identity - get collection of users in "admin" or "adminlower" roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I can get a collection of all users and order them with some Linq like this:

```
var Users = UserManager.Users.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated)
```

I'd like to restrict users returned to those with the role "admin" or "adminlower". I've searched a lot and found things like this but they don't help:

http://aryalnishan.com.np/asp-net-mvc/list-all-users-with-associated-roles-in-asp-net-identity/

I've tried this, also doesn't work:

```
var AdminRoles = new string[] { "admin", "adminlower" };
var Roles = RoleManager.Roles;
Roles.Contains(AdminRoles);
```

I just can't seem to get the syntax, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but you're probably looking for something similar:

You could get the `roleId` this way.

```
var roleManager= new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

//Get admin role
var adminRole= roleManager.FindByName("Admin");

var admins=context.Users.Where(x=>x.Roles.Any(role=>role.RoleId==adminRole.Id)).ToList().OrderBy(d=>d.DateCreated);
```

Another option may be to **load** all users, then loop through using `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync` to filter the Admins. But you don't want to do that unless you have reasonably small user base.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking along these lines, but there's no role.Name, there is only Role.RoleId

Comment: Sorry slight query - the OP was for multiple roles not just one. Any chance of a quick update? Thx.

Comment: Can't test this but should be straightforward. `var adminLowerRole=roleManager.FindByName("adminlower");` Then : `var admins=context.Users.Where(x=>x.Roles.Any(role=>role.RoleId==adminRole.Id|| role.RoleId==adminLowerRole.Id)).ToList().OrderBy(d=>d.DateCreated);` You should get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of user by a single role there is a build-in method in UserManager. You can try the following:

```
var adminUsers = (await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("rolename")).ToList();
```

That should solve your problem.